# Find a rule for the number of items to be stocked in order to maximize the expected income

Tags: probability, optimization, expectation

This is a simplified inventory problem. Suppose that it costs $c$ dollars to stock an item and that the item sells for $s$ dollars. Suppose that the number of items that will be asked for by customers is a random variable with the frequency function $p(k)$. Find a rule for the number of items that should be stocked in order to maximize the expected income. (*Hint:* Consider the difference of successive terms.)

The answer given by the textbook is: That value of $n$ such that $s \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}  p(k) > c \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} p(k) $ and $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}  p(k) > c \sum_{k=1}^{n} p(k)$.

I don't really understand why that is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you pay stock fees for all items you carry or only for those that go unsold?

Comment: That is not specified in the question.

Comment: Let $D$ be the actual random demand of the items with the given pmf $p(k)$, and $n$ be the number of items stocked. Can you express the income in terms of $c, s, n, D$? And can you write down the expression of the expected income?

Comment: By the way this is the question 4.9 from the 3rd edition of the John A. Rice's book Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis. A good tip is available here: https://www.talkstats.com/threads/simplified-inventory-problem.29953/ .